# Determine which DFS referral target a user is using

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs, namespaces

Our DFS namespace is set-up so that \\company.local\users is hosted on both a UK server and USA server with referral based upon the user's site. Works a treat except we suspect today, DFS failed over to the USA for some users. Only suspect because the only evidence we can see is their private files (e.g. cookies, roaming profile) replicating BACK from the USA. Normally, they go the other way.

How can a user determine where \company.local\users is resolving to in their session? Is there a command line tool or something they can look at? Something like net use but for DFS namespaces.

Thanks, Rob.

Comment: Ohh and of course, user's complaining slow access to their "My Documents"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dfsutil /PktInfo will give you the information you're looking for, but you need to get dfsutil for the applicable client, either from the RSAT for Windows 7 or from the W2K3 Support Tools for WinXP. Run the command on the client and it will show you the active target.

Comment: Thanks - works a treat. We use Citrix XenApp on Windows 2003 so dfsutil was already installed. Not the more user friendly output but it does allow one to see where ACTIVE TARGETSET is pointing

Comment: Glad to help...